# Из чего должен состоять api запрос?

Tags: c#, api

Пишу market запрос по [документации](https://huobiapi.github.io/docs/spot/v1/en/#place-a-new-order) . Создать новый ордер не получается.Чего не хватает в запросе?Там написано что в количестве нужно указывать order value.Что под этим словосочетаниям имеется ввиду не понимаю.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.huobi.pro");
var request = new RestRequest("/v1/order/orders/place");
request.AddQueryParameter("account-id", "315043256");
request.AddQueryParameter("amount", "10");
request.AddQueryParameter("symbol", "expbtc");
request.AddQueryParameter("type", "buy-market");
request.AddQueryParameter("AccessKeyId", apikey);
request.AddQueryParameter("SignatureMethod", "HmacSHA256");
request.AddQueryParameter("SignatureVersion", "2");
request.AddQueryParameter("Timestamp", UTCtime());
var response = client.Post(request);
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что `AddQueryParameter` - это генерация JSON? Указанный вами сайт просит тело в формате JSON, а судя по документации библиотеки, что вы используете (не пойму кстати зачем), тело делается там так `new RestRequest("/v1/order/orders/place", DataFormat.Json).AddJsonBody(new { A = "foo", B = "bar" });`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ До этого делал get запросы все было хорошо, теперь пишет ошибка сигнатуры.Решили сделать по вашему совету `account-id="3142406"` рисует ошибку .

Comment: А какую ошибку, конечно, гадать нам, да? Отловите запрос, который вы отправляете и смотрите чтобы там было тело JSON! Научитесь при помощи вашей библиотеки сериализовать грамотно данные. А вообще, советую научиться использовать стандартные механизмы языка, а уж затем, думать о библиотеках.

Comment: Вангую, что не выставили тип запроса - а потому что не читали [документацию](https://huobiapi.github.io/docs/spot/v1/en/#q6-why-the-signature-authentication-always-fail): `The Content-Type in POST header should be application/json`. Это просто бич современности: надо полностью прочитать документацию, но хочется сразу в бой пробовать. А там наверняка все вопросы ваши уже отвечены.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Как реализовать данный фрагмент в моем случае ` All parameters are formatted as JSON and put int the request body`?Перевод - Все параметры отформатированы в формате JSON и помещены в тело запроса

Comment: @AK После полного перевода статьи мне все равно не совсем понятно из чего должен состоять запрос.

Comment: @Keks Я вроде сказал как, не? Для начала отловите запрос, который вы отправляете, посмотрите что вы шлете серверу, какие данные, в каком виде, достаточно установить Fiddler или нечто подобное. Ну а дальше уже смотрите чем отличается отправляемый вами запрос от того, что требует сервер. Тело JSON я также написал выше, судя по документации к библиотеки (не пойму зачем она), при инициализации `RestRequest` должен быть указан тип (`new RestRequest(.., DataFormat.Json)`), а дальше добавляется само тело при помощи метода `.AddJsonBody()`.